# Multiple rapid asynchronous ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, jsonp

I'd like to run multiple asynchronous ajax calls to a server on another domain (I use jquery and jsonp for X domain calls). When I do single calls from time to time, then everything works fine. However, if I run multiple different calls to different URL's with different callbacks then all calls are aborted (according to firebug). The script below allows to reproduce the issue fairly well. My apache server is on http://domain.com:80.

```
var urls=new Array();
urls.push("https://domain.com:9943/stuff?callback=fnReturn");
urls.push("https://domain.com:9943/stuff?callback=fnReturn2");
urls.push("https://domain.com:9943/stuff?callback=fnReturn3");
for(var i=0;i<urls.length;i++){
    uri = urls[i];
    var tmp=uri.split("=");
    jsonWrapperFunction=tmp[tmp.length-1];
    console.log("calling: "+uri);
    var xhr=$.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type:"GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: uri,
        timeout: 60000,
        success: function(response) {
                console.log("WORKING"+response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log("ERROR"+error);
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: jsonWrapperFunction
    });


}
```

When I run this on chrome I get the following error :
GET https://domain.com:9943&callback=fnReturn&_=1444944920008 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
send @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4m.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4

In firefox, the request is aborted immediately. However, if I put a little timeout(sleep) in between the calls, then they tend to work.

My first thought was on conflicting XMLHTTPRequest objects, but couldn't find any hint on how to make this work.

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: I would suggest letting jQuery specify it's own jsonp callback. Also note that contentType and crossDomain do nothing for jsonp requests.

Comment: *"My first thought was on conflicting XMLHTTPRequest objects, but couldn't find any hint on how to make this work."* JSONP requests don't use XMLHTTPRequest objects, so that's definitely not the case.

Comment: Ok, I stripped of contentType and crossDomain and use jquery defined jsonp callbacks throughout. I still see the issue if I call various different webservices at the same time. However, if I call always the same one with different parameters, then everything works fine. Still not sure how to track down the problem.